# Uploading data from matlab to firebase

Tags: json, matlab, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase creates a name for the data i upload from matlab.
is there a way to cancel this name? or set it to something constant so the next time i upload ill overwrite it?

Example:

https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/3/24/0cb9e3c19155a8b338806121aed42ea2-full.jpg
(i want the data from matlab to be the same structure like the adc sample)

This is the code I use:

```
Firebase_Url = 'https://***.firebaseio.com/data_from_matlab.json/';
response = webwrite(Firebase_Url,'{ "first": "Jack", "last": "Sparrow" }')
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [Matlab's `webwrite` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/webwrite.html) sends a HTTP `POST` request, which [Firebase's REST API translates to create a new node with a new unique ID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#section-ways-to-save).

It looks like you can pass `RequestMethod: 'put'` in the [`weboptions`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/weboptions.html) parameter to send a `PUT` request, which Firebase translation to a direct write at the location. So something like:

```
webwrite(Firebase_Url,'{ "first": "Jack", "last": "Sparrow" }',
         weboptions("RequestMethod", "put"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually was having a similar problem but I wanted to add multiple objects with different names and when I used `RequestMethod: 'put'` in `weboptions` Firebase deleted my old objects. I looked into the [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#section-ways-to-save) given above I discovered that using `RequestMethod: 'patch'` I could add multiple objects under the same category without getting the randomly generated key.